# What happens if I visit a page with a campaign id?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-analytics, sitecore-exm

if open a page with a campaign id, for example

```
mysite.com?sc_camp=0ED397C4784E4FA1834897A35461992A
```

can anyone tell me what exactly should happen in that moment?

If I look into my analytics dashboard, everything under Campaigns it is empty (No data to display). Checked Mongo DB but did not find anything that looked like campaigns. Checked the reporting DB, there is a campaigns table but there are no columns for a count or a last triggered date.

We made some changes to our tracking for GDPR but I am not sure if the campaigns and goals are still working correctly, can anyone tell me in which Table I need to check after I have triggered a campaign?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if that campaign ID actually matches any campaign defined in your site? The information should be visible in the Experience Analytics. 
Also, check the logs as it might give you some information.